# Moving Draw() code to a Class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame

I'm creating a game in monogame, and I've loaded tiles in my game inside the `Draw()` function like so:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();   
        spriteBatch.Draw(danChar, charPosition, Color.White);

        // loop below loads the 'grass' tiles only

        // assuming gameworld size of 770x450
        for (int i = 0; i < 770; i += 31) // adds 31 to i (per tile)
        {
            position = new Vector2(i, 392); // places incrementation into vector position
            spriteBatch.Draw(gameTile, position, Color.White); // draws the tile each time
            if (i == 744)
            {
                i = i + 26; // fills last space between 744 and 770
                position = new Vector2(i, 392);
            }
            spriteBatch.Draw(gameTile, position, Color.White); 
        }

        // loop below loads the brick tiles only (ones without grass)

        spriteBatch.End();  // ends the spriteBatch call
        base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

However I would prefer that this was a separate class rather than being placed directly into the draw function, however I'm not too sure how to do this and would appreciate any help given.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much experience do you have with writing classes?

Comment: Another thing you can use is a [DrawableGameComponent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to move the code as is to another class, create your class (e.g. something like `GameWorld` seems to appropriate for your code)

```
public class GameWorld
{
    // You may wish to move your gameTile definition into this class if it is the only
    // class that uses it, and handle the content loading for it in here.
    // e.g. if you're currently loading the texture in the LoadContent method in your game
    // class, create a LoadContent method here and pass in ContentManger as a parameter.
    // I've passed in the texture as a parameter to the Draw method in this example to
    // simplify as I'm not sure how you're managing your textures.

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, GameTime gameTime, Texture2D gameTile)
    {
        // loop below loads the 'grass' tiles only

        // assuming gameworld size of 770x450
        for (int i = 0; i < 770; i += 31) // adds 31 to i (per tile)
        {
            Vector2 position = new Vector2(i, 392); // places incrementation into vector position
            spriteBatch.Draw(gameTile, position, Color.White); // draws the tile each time
            if (i == 744)
            {
                i = i + 26; // fills last space between 744 and 770
                position = new Vector2(i, 392);
            }
            spriteBatch.Draw(gameTile, position, Color.White); 
        }

        // loop below loads the brick tiles only (ones without grass)   
    }
}
```

Then the Draw method in your `Game` class would look like

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();   
        spriteBatch.Draw(danChar, charPosition, Color.White);

        // Assuming you've created/loaded an instance of the GameWorld class
        // called gameWorld in Initialize/LoadContent
        gameWorld.Draw(spriteBatch, gameTime, gameTile);

        spriteBatch.End();  // ends the spriteBatch call
        base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Just make sure you're calling the `Draw` methods in the correct order. e.g. you want your player to appear above any background tiles.

I believe the default `SpriteSortMode` is `Deferred` which draws in the order the calls are made (i.e. from the back to the front).

You can specify a different `SpriteSortMode` in your call to `spriteBatch.Begin()` if you need to but for a simple game just move the `Draw` calls around.

More info on `SpriteSortMode` at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx) if needed.

Similarly you can chain your `Update`, `LoadContent` methods into these classes if you wish, making sure to pass in anything you need as arguments.

**Update:**

To define `gameWorld` as an instance of the `GameWorld` class, you define it near the top of your game class, then typically initialize it in the `Initialize` method.

So your game class will look something like

```
public class MyGameName : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    // other variable declarations

    // Add a declaration for gameWorld
    private GameWorld gameWorld;

    protected override Initialize()
    {
        // Add the following line to initialize your gameWorld instance
        gameWorld = new GameWorld();
    }

    // other existing code - your LoadContent, Update, Draw methods etc.
}
```

Comment: This nearly works, but I'm just curious, when you said `// Assuming you've created/loaded an instance of the GameWorld class called gameWorld`, how exactly would you do that, because I seem to have a slight error otherwise.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to declare/initialize gameWorld. Note that the code is just a short sample, you'll have a lot of other code in there. It's just to illustrate the syntax and where the lines go.